# View multiple Point Clouds in same window using PCL in C++

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I have two point cloud, which I want to visualise in the same window.

```
#include <pcl/io/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>

int main ()
{
    pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Cloud Viewer");

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr body (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("body.pcd", *body);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr head (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("head.pcd", *head);

    viewer.showCloud (body);
    viewer.showCloud (head);
    while (!viewer.wasStopped ())
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can see only the last PCD file.

*Please note that I don't want to use pcd_viewer tool since I need to do some other processing on this data.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the comment

*"Okay. I will check it soon. Can you tell me to set camera parameters and background color using cloud_viewer API?"*

I am not 100% sure if you can do this using `pcl::visualization::CloudViewer`. However, if you move your code to `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer` you can do `viewer.setBackgroundColor(double red,double green,double blue)` (where the values range 0..1. To set a camera). For the camera, you can use  [`pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::setCameraPosition`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#a2232b62d2dd1caead79df190731b810c). Moving your code from CloudViewer to PCLVisualizer is preatty easy.

```
#include <pcl/io/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

int main ()
{
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("Cloud Viewer");

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr body (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("body.pcd", *body);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr head (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("head.pcd", *head);

    viewer.addPointCloud (body,"body");// note that before it was showCloud
    viewer.addPointCloud (head,"head");// note that before it was showCloud
    viewer.spin();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
Ther is acutally a way to do this. By looking into [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cloud_viewer.php), you can see that you can run any of the function of the `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer` using the `pcl::visualization::CloudViewer::runOnVisualizationThreadOnce` or `pcl::visualization::CloudViewer::runOnVisualizationThread` functions. For this, you will need to create a function that does all the part that uses `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer`and pass it to the `CloudViewer::runOnVisualizationThreadOnce` or `CloudViewer::runOnVisualizationThread`.

For example

```
#include <pcl/io/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>

void 
setBackground (pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer& viewer)
{
    viewer.setBackgroundColor (1.0, 0.5, 1.0);    
}

int main ()
{
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("Cloud Viewer");

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr body (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("body.pcd", *body);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr head (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("head.pcd", *head);

    viewer.showCloud (body,"body");
    viewer.showCloud (head,"head");

    viewer.runOnVisualizationThreadOnce(setBackground);

    while (!viewer.wasStopped ())
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The only issue is that I do not see how you could potentially pass arguments to the `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer` function that you want to use in the function we crated (in the previous example `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::setBackgroundColor`in `setBackground`. For this, I think using directly `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer` is much better.

Answer (score 3):

As per [the pcl documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_cloud_viewer.html#a845aa739fa2ed4c3e57a07e762a48c2b), you can provide a name for the display point cloud.
If you provide the same name it overwrites the existing cloud.

This basically means changing the following calls:

```
viewer.showCloud (body);
viewer.showCloud (head);
```

With:

```
viewer.showCloud (body, "body");
viewer.showCloud (head, "head");
```

of course you can use whatever names you want.

Comment: Okay. I will check it soon. Can you tell me to set camera parameters and background color using *cloud_viewer* API?

Comment: Do you think that [PCL Visualizer](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.5.1/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html) is a better option? Is it possible to view multiple clouds on PCL Visualizer?

Comment: You can use the method [runOnVisualizationThread()](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_cloud_viewer.html#ae657abe24e9345e09ab58fb664fafe68). Just give it a function of what you want to do on the visualization thread. The function argument is a PCLVisualizer. Honestly I am not that well-versed in PCL

Answer (score 1):

```
  pclPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr head (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr body (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

 //initialize the point cloud viewer
  pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer ("");

 //visualize head
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZ>  source_cloud_color_handler (head, 230, 20, 20);
  viewer.addPointCloud (head, source_cloud_color_handler, "head");

  //visualize body
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZ> transformed_cloud_color_handler (body, 255, 255, 255); // Whiite
  viewer.addPointCloud (body, transformed_cloud_color_handler, "body");

  viewer.addCoordinateSystem (1.0, "body", 0);
  viewer.setBackgroundColor(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0); // Setting background to a dark grey
  viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 2, "head");
```