# PCL: merging two sets of points to one cloud and visualizeing with PCL cloudviewer

Tags: visualization, point-cloud-library

I am trying to merge two sets of points from two different views to one single point cloud and visualize it with PCL cloud viewer.

```
    mPtrPointCloud->points.clear();
    mPtrPointCloud->points.resize(mFrameSize * 2);
    auto it = mPtrPointCloud->points.begin();
    received = PopReceived();
    if(received != nullptr)
    {
        // p_data_cloud = (float*)received->mTransformedPC.data;
        p_data_cloud = (float*)received->mCVPointCloud.data;
        index = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < mFrameSize; ++i) 
        {
            float X = p_data_cloud[index];
            if (!isValidMeasure(X)) // Checking if it's a valid point
            {
                it->x = it->y = it->z = it->rgb = 0;
            }
            else 
            {
                it->x = X;
                it->y = p_data_cloud[index + 1];
                it->z = p_data_cloud[index + 2];
                it->rgb = convertColor(p_data_cloud[index + 3]); // Convert a 32bits float into a pcl .rgb format
            }
            index += 4;
            ++it;
        }
    }

    frame = PopFrame();
    if(frame != nullptr)
    {
        // p_data_cloud = frame->mSLPointCloud.getPtr<float>();
        p_data_cloud = (float*)frame->mCVPointCloud.data;
        index = 0;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < mFrameSize; ++i) 
        {
            float X = p_data_cloud[index];
            if (!isValidMeasure(X)) // Checking if it's a valid point
            {
                it->x = it->y = it->z = it->rgb = 0;
            }
            else 
            {
                it->x = X;
                it->y = p_data_cloud[index + 1];
                it->z = p_data_cloud[index + 2];
                it->rgb = convertColor(p_data_cloud[index + 3]); // Convert a 32bits float into a pcl .rgb format
            }
                index += 4;
                ++it;
            }
        }
mPtrPCViewer->showCloud(mPtrPointCloud);
```

What I want to have is two sets of points are "fused" to one frame. However, it seems these two sets of points are still shown separately one after the other.

Could anyone help to explain how to really merge two sets of points into one cloud? Thanks

Comment: how are you acquiring those points clouds?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Create a new empty pointcloud which will be the merged pointcloud at the end

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>  mPtrPointCloud;
```

(2) Transform point clouds to origin

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> recieved_transformed;
Eigen::Transform<Scalar, 3, Eigen::Affine> recieved_transformation_mat(recieved.sensor_origin_ * recieved.sensor_orientation_);
pcl::transformPointCloud(recieved, recieved_transformed, recieved_transformation_mat);

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> frame_transformed;
Eigen::Transform<Scalar, 3, Eigen::Affine> frame_transformation_mat(frame.sensor_origin_ * frame.sensor_orientation_);
pcl::transformPointCloud(frame, frame_transformed, frame_transformation_mat);
```

(3) Use the += operator

```
mPtrPointCloud += received_transformed;
mPtrPointCloud += frame_transformed;
```

(4) Visualize merged pointcloud

```
mPtrPCViewer->showCloud(mPtrPointCloud);
```

That's it. See also example http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/concatenate_clouds.php
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/matrix_transform.php

Comment: This has the same effect as my current solution, since they are both adding points to one cloud. However, showing the two clouds with different name can solve the problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45783815/view-multiple-point-clouds-in-same-window-using-pcl-in-c). I don't fully understand it now. I am thinking if this is related to the buffer management of PCL.

Comment: Can it be that your two clouds have different transformations? If you merge this information is lost.

Comment: I don't quite sure your meaning of different transformations. Do you mean different camera poses? They are taken with different poses. However, even so, they have some overlapping with each other. I think it should be possible to merge them in same view. And with the method in the link, I can see them with a same view.

Comment: Yes I mean camera poses. The viewer loads the two separate point clouds from their respective camera pose. That's why it works. If you want to concatenate two point clouds from two different camera poses you have to transform each of them to the origin first and then you can merge them. Updated answer!

Comment: Do you mean the two camera poses should have have the same origin?